# Create Activity in Viewpager - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I was trying to figure out how to create activity ( there are 3 imagebutton) from imagebutton in viewpager. I am a beginner and creating my first app.

Here is my main_java

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private DcDesignPageAdapter dcDesignPageAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dc_design);

    SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    dcDesignPageAdapter = new DcDesignPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(dcDesignPageAdapter);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dc_design, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here is my fragment code

```
public class DcDesignFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ImageButtonIDKey = "imagebuttonkey";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(fragment_dcdesigns, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        if(bundle != null) {

            int imageButtonID = bundle.getInt(ImageButtonIDKey);

            displayValues(view, imageButtonID);
        }
        return view;
    }

    private void displayValues(View view, int imageButtonID) {
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setImageResource(imageButtonID);
    }
}
```

And here is my PageAdapter

```
String[] dcdesigns;

public DcDesignPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    dcdesigns = resources.getStringArray(R.array.dcdesigns);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(DcDesignFragment.ImageButtonIDKey,getDcdesignsImageButtonID(position));

    DcDesignFragment dcDesignFragment = new DcDesignFragment();
    dcDesignFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return dcDesignFragment;
}

private int getDcdesignsImageButtonID(int position) {
    int id = 0;
    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            id = R.drawable.1;
            break;
        case 1:
            id = R.drawable.2;
            break;
        case 2:
            id = R.drawable.3;
    }

    return id;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return dcdesigns[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dcdesigns.length;
}
```

Thank you very much, any help would appreciated.

Comment: So what is the problem that you are having?

Comment: I want to move to another activity when user click on the imagebutton.

Comment: Add an onClickListener to the ImageButton. Call getActivity() (from within the Fragment) to get a reference to the Activity and use the startActivity method passing in your Intent to start the Activity.

Comment: Would you help to guide me in this? I have zero coding knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Fragment simply put an onClickListener to the ImageButton. You can use the getActivity() method to get a reference to the parent Activity. Use the startActivity() method to start an Activity. Your new displayValues() method in your DcDesignFragment:

```
private void displayValues(View view, int imageButtonID) {
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setImageResource(imageButtonID);
    imageButtonnew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Create your intent
            //Replace "NextActivity" with your Activity name.
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
            //This will launch your new Activity
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Also, make sure your next Activity is declared in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

**Update:** Your updated displayValues() method in regards to your comment:

```
private void displayValues(View view, final int imageButtonID) {
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setImageResource(imageButtonID);
    imageButtonnew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            switch(imageButtonID){
                default:
                case R.drawable.1:
                    //Create your intent
                    //Replace "NextActivity1" with your Activity name.
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity1.class);
                    break;
                case R.drawable.2:
                    //Replace "NextActivity2" with your Activity name.
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity2.class);
                    break;
                case R.drawable.3:
                    //Replace "NextActivity3" with your Activity name.
                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity3.class);
                    break;
            }
            //This will launch your new Activity
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: That work perfectly!! Another question, if I want to add different activity to second and third imagebutton, how can I do that?

Comment: @Cassie.L You would do the same thing that you did to this ImageButton but change the second parameter in the Intent constructor. For instance, instead of `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);` you would do `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OtherActivity.class);`

Comment: I tried this but does not work. " Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), 1.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), 2.class);

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I get it now!

Comment: @Cassie.L glad to hear and you're welcome!

Comment: When I run the app again, the result is not how i expect. So, in the fragment I have return 3 imagebuttons and each imagebutton lead to different activity. How should I code this. Thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you displaying only one button but are changing the background?

Comment: So I have a total of 3 imagebuttons in viewpager and i want each button lead to different activity.

Comment: @Cassie.L To me it looks like you have one Fragment that contains one ImageButton. But you are passing it a different image resource for that one ImageButton via your getDcdesignsImageButtonID method. In which case you will have to have another switch statement in the onclicklistener for what image ID it is using.

Comment: Yes, that's sounds right, where should I add the switch statement, I hope you can still guide through this.

Comment: @Cassie.L see my updated answer.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you